# Upgrade PostgreSQL from 9.5 to newer version and move DB to different machine

Tags: postgresql

I have two task to do:

- Move database from VM with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to VM with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Database is stored on mounted HDD. (Azure)
- Update postgresql 9.5 to newer version.

What is the smartest way to achive that with minimal downtime?

Comment: If it's safe I can go straight to 12. I changed the title :)

Answer (score 0):

With minimal downtime but with lots of work:  [Upgrading Data via Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/upgrading.html#UPGRADING-VIA-REPLICATION)

Comment: I've considered this, but is it possible for the 9.5 version? The documentation says it's a 10+ option - or I'm wrong.

Comment: You can use pglogical which is available for PostgreSQL 9.4 and later:https://www.2ndquadrant.com/fr/resources/pglogical/

Comment: Looks like it's worth a try. You tested it successfully?

Comment: No I didn't test these kind of upgrades.